# IOS: merge ImageView and UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage

I want put over an UIImage a small UIImageView and I want as result an UIImage, what can I do?

Comment: The `UIImageView` has an associated `UIImage`, so what you really want is to “merge” two `UIImage`s. Now what do you mean by “merging”? Simply painting one over the other?

Answer (score 2):

You have to create a new graphics context (`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()`), then draw the two images into the context (`-[UIImage drawInRect:]`), and then retrieve an image from the context (`UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`).

Don't forget to call `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` at the end.

Comment: No, I won't. I pretty much listed every single call that you need above. With the help of the documentation, you should be able to figure out the rest pretty easily.

Comment: blackguardian, at least try yourself first and ask then for assistance if you have a problem.